# Understanding Graph, Weighted method

Tags: string, generics, input, inputstream, graph-algorithm

Okay, so what does the SET stand for in the second line? Why is the second string in<>, ?

```
public Weighted(In in, String delimiter) {

    st = new ST<String, SET<String>>();
    while (!in.isEmpty()) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        String[] names = line.split(delimiter);
        for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
            addEdge(names[0], names[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the little information you gave, I will assume that SET is an abstract data type. An abstract data type can store any values without any particular order and with no duplicates. By telling `<String>` after SET you are telling you want to store Strings inside your SET.

You can learn more about SETs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)